# Draw a function given by a system of equations involving an implicit function

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I need to draw a graph of a function like this:

[image]

What is the most elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the substitution `x = cos(t)` to parameterise your set of equations for t ∈ [0, 2π) as `x = cos(t)`, `y = sin(t)`, `z = 2x`.

In Julia, you can use [Plots.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl) to plot this as follows:

```
using Plots
t = 0:0.01:2*pi
x = cos.(t)
y = sin.(t)
z = 2 .* x

plot(x, y, z)
```

A slightly neater trick is to use [*parametric plotting*](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/plotly/#plotly-ref3), where we can just pass functions (x(t), y(t), z(t)) and specify the range of the parameter t:

```
plot(cos, sin, x -> 2 * cos(x), 0, 2π, xlabel="x", ylabel="y", zlabel="z", label="f")
```